# Solving Laplace's equation

Tags: python, physics, equation

i'm trying to solve Laplace's equation with a particular geometry (two circular conductors), here's what i've done in python :

```
    from __future__ import division
from pylab import *
from scipy import *
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import *

N1=50 # number of points along x and y 
N=2*N1+1 # number of points in total
# in cm.
xc1=4
xc2=9
yc1=0
yc2=0
R1=1.75
R2=9
ecart = 1



a, b = linspace(-1, 19, N), linspace(-10, 10, N)
xa, ya = meshgrid(a, b) 
V = zeros_like(xa)


for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        x, y = xa[i,j], ya[i,j]
        if (((x-xc1)**2/(R1**2))+((y-yc1)**2/(R1**2)))<=1 : # potential in the central conductor
            V[i,j] = 30
        if (((x-xc2)**2/(R2**2))+((y-yc2)**2/(R2**2)))>=1 : # potential in the outer conductor
            V[i,j] =0

#draws the potential along X along the axis of symmetry.


Vnew = V.copy()

while ecart > 5*10**-2:

  for i in range(1,N-1):

   for j in range(1,N-1):

    Vnew[i,j] = 0.25*(V[i-1,j] + V[i+1,j] + V [i,j-1] + V[i,j+1])

  # convergence criterion

  ecart = np.max(np.abs(V - (Vnew))/np.max(V))

  print(ecart)
  # save in the grid V of the calculated grid
  for i in range(N): 
        for j in range(N):
            x, y = xa[i,j], ya[i,j]
            if (((x-xc1)**2/(R1**2))+((y-yc1)**2/(R1**2))) > 1 and (((x-xc2)**2/(R2**2))+((y-yc2)**2/(R2**2))) < 1 :
                    V[i,j] = Vnew[i,j]
```

it actually works with `ecart>5*10**-2`, but I would like to do it with `ecart>10**-3` and here is the problem, it takes too much time ,actually it never ends...
Does someone have any idea in order to improve the program ? 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: It would be interesting to point out whether the `print(ecart)` prints anything, if yes, if there's a last value and then nothing, etc.

Comment: It would be (very) difficult to say anything new on this topic. Profile your code to see what's slow, vectorise where possible, take repetitive calculations outside loops, and so on. Skim google hits for applicable ideas.

Comment: I tried to run the code with some different values for `N`, and it seems that this value has an influence on the "final" value of `ecart`. It might be that you need a higher value of `N` to get the tolerance you need. (Of course, a higher `N` means a longer time per iteration). Using `ecart=5e-2` and `N=50`  took me 422 iterations, while using `N = 100`  took 154 iterations.

Comment: I neglected to mention https://pypy.org/.

Comment: Do you mean the *Poisson equation* (non-zero charge density) ? If so, try using the Fourier Transform method. [Here](https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Poisson%27s-Equation-Using-Fourier-Transforms) and [here](http://www.ucdenver.edu/academics/colleges/CLAS/Departments/math/graduateprograms/alumni/alumni/Documents/Student%20Theses/Bradford_PhDThesis.pdf) are two examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! The charge density is equal to 0 here because we have conductors

Comment: I think I will keep `ecart = 5e-2`...